# Objective-C To Swift: void (^safeHandler)(UIBackgroundFetchResult)

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am porting some AppDelegate code for a plugin Objective-C to Swift.

My Objective-C is pretty good but I am stumped at understanding whats going on here. This is the code I am stuck on porting:

```
    void (^safeHandler)(UIBackgroundFetchResult) = ^(UIBackgroundFetchResult result){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completionHandler(result);
        });
    };
```

I understand that the the `^` is for code blocks, but looking at this as a whole I am lost as to what is going on and how to port this to Swift.

I don't understand how there are two bracketed portions here:

```
void (^safeHandler)(UIBackgroundFetchResult)
```

If you can advise what that syntax is and how to port to Swift I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a block, which is a closure in Swift.  This block is named `safeHandler` and takes a `UIBackgroundFetchResult` parameter and returns `void`.

This is the equivalent  type:

```
let safeHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> ()
```

And the whole thing would be

```
let safeHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> () = { result in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        completionHandler(result)
    }
}
```

Note: block syntax is notoriously wonky.  You can use this site to see the various block syntax forms: http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/